# Electromagnet Halbach arrays

Tags: electromagnetism, halbach-array

Could a set of electromagnets be arranged in a [Halbach array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halbach_array)? If so, what would happen if only half were turned on? And if polarity were reversed? I have researched thoroughly, and I found a [post on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Will-putting-electromagnets-in-halbach-array-produce-a-stronger-magnetic-field), but the poster's grammar prevented me from gaining any information. To prevent this from being closed as `too broad`, I just want information as to whether this would work, and maybe some of the other questions I listed above.

Comment: A row of electromagnets with alternating winding direction, backed on one side with soft iron?

Comment: @Pieter Yes, exactly like a normal Halbach Array, but with electromagnets rather than permanent ones.